# Samsung Phones Do Not Loop Video (Other phones do)

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediaplayer

I have a `videoView` that plays a loop. Pretty simple:

```
    Log.d("","Start Video");
    _videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    _videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            Log.d("","Loop Video");
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

On non-Samsung phones, this works perfectly, the video loops infinitely. On Samsung phones, it calls the "Loop Video" portion but it doesn't actually loop.

Any suggestions on a work around to this or insight as to why the video doesn't loop?

Answer (score 0):

I had to code in a workaround that restarts it on completion. Its a hack, but it gets the job done:

```
    _videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            _videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
            _videoView.start();
        }
    });
```